# How do I get the JavaScript code that fires a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am trying to implement a modal pop up for my project and I found what I wanted in a jsfiddle. I can find out what the html and CSS is that they are using for the modal, but I don't know what js are they using?

Can you tell me what JavaScript are they using for the modal?  That is when I click the log in button the modal pop up opens up:

http://jsfiddle.net/VSsLC/

http://jsfiddle.net/VSsLC/embedded/result/

Here is the html code below:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="login-modal" style="display: none;">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h1>Log in to Kippt</h1>
    
    <form class="connect-button" name="login" method="post" action="/social/twitter/redirect/" id="twitter-connect-form">
    <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="MNH48hjwVMrGUWcpNqIt4qa1nko6RWdo"></div>
    
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#twitter-connect-form').submit(); return false;" class="signup-twitter signup-btn" id="twitter_button"><i></i>Log in with Twitter</a>
    </form>
    <form class="connect-button" name="login" method="post" action="/social/facebook/redirect/" id="facebook-connect-form">
      <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="MNH48hjwVMrGUWcpNqIt4qa1nko6RWdo"></div>
      
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#facebook-connect-form').submit(); return false;" class="signup-facebook signup-btn" id="facebook_button"><i></i>Log in  with Facebook</a>
      </form>

      <form action="/login" method="POST" autocomplete="off"><div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="MNH48hjwVMrGUWcpNqIt4qa1nko6RWdo"></div>
        
        <fieldset>
            <h5>or with Kippt account</h5>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username or email" name="username" maxlength="30" id="id_username">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="id_password">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn">
        </fieldset>
         <a href="/accounts/password/reset/"><span>Forgot password?</span></a> · <a href="/signup/"><span>Sign up to Kippt</span></a>
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just post the direct link to the https://kippt.com/ site, asking on how they created their sign-up form.
It is clear that their Javascript is way too obfuscated to understand anything useful, but I did see that they use **jQuery**. By doing a small google search, I found that there is a very similar effect library called **bootstrap modal**.
You must consider the possibility that they wrote this effect for themselves, using jQuery.

Comment: can u tell me in the above fiddle what js are they using for modal

Comment: I can see the bootstrap I mentioned, the http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js and https://api.mixpanel.com/site_media/js/api/mixpanel.js

Comment: i am asking a particular js file for modal

Comment: There is no particular file for the modal functionality. It is either a part of a library, or custom-made, by the original website programmers. You should try to re-create the functionality, by understanding what it does, and applying the jQuery effects to imitate it, rather than searching for a "copy-paste-replace div names" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but if I well understood, you're looking for js files. So you can go to any browser with a good bunch of developpers tool (chrome, firefox, safari). For example, in Chrome, go the developper tools, to display the console (cmd+option+i on the mac), go to resssources/Frames/Scripts, and you'll find the js files

Comment: i am not able to find the js file for the pop up